# Direct X 11 Overlay - Text Rendering Issue

Tags: c++, visual-c++, directx, overlay, directx-11

I have an ongoing project that utilizes DirectX 11 to overlay text on an external window (without injecting anything or using any kind of internal API hooks). I'm creating a transparent window and using FW1FontWrapper to handle the actual text drawing. The problem I'm experiencing is that the text has artifacts and looks distorted, depending on the current color of the window I am drawing over. When the window is light- colored, it causes the text to be essentially unreadable, while drawing on a dark- colored backgrounds/ windows makes it look mostly normal.

For an example of what I am talking about, see the following two images (text over dark-colored and light-colored windows respectively):

[image: Text over dark- colored window (normal)]

[image: Text over light- colored window]

My guess is that the issue resides somewhere in my Direct X initialization code. Either that or the blending of alpha channels across the text and the underlying window. My direct X implementation uses the following code during initialization:

```
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0;

DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scd;

// clear out the struct for use
ZeroMemory(&scd, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));

// fill the swap chain description struct
scd.BufferCount = 1;                                    // one back buffer
scd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;     // use 32-bit color
scd.BufferDesc.Width = ScreenWidth;                     // set the back buffer width
scd.BufferDesc.Height = ScreenHeight;                   // set the back buffer height
scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;      // how swap chain is to be used
scd.OutputWindow = handleWindow;                        // the window to be used
scd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;                               // how many multisamples
scd.Windowed = TRUE;    
scd.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
scd.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;
scd.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
scd.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;     // allow full-screen switching  

D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL  FeatureLevelsSupported;

// create a device, device context and swap chain using the information in the scd struct
D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL,
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
    NULL,
    0,
    &featureLevel,
    1,
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
    &scd,
    &m_pSwapchain,
    &m_pDevice,
    &FeatureLevelsSupported,
    &m_pContext);


// get the address of the back buffer
ID3D11Texture2D *pBackBuffer;
m_pSwapchain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&pBackBuffer);

// use the back buffer address to create the render target
m_pDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBuffer, NULL, &m_pBackBuffer);
pBackBuffer->Release();

// set the render target as the back buffer
m_pContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_pBackBuffer, NULL);

// Set the viewport
D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
ZeroMemory(&viewport, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));

viewport.MinDepth = 0;
viewport.MaxDepth = 1;
viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
viewport.Width = ScreenWidth;
viewport.Height = ScreenHeight;

m_pContext->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);
```

FW1FontWrapper is initialized using all default parameters.

I hope someone with more experience in this area will notice what is going wrong here, or at least, point me in the right direction. I have spent endless hours trying to find the solution. I will provide any additional information or code if it will make things more clear.

Comment: This looks like text is rendered without alpha channel. Or with opaque alpha. So semitransparent parts have colour from the render target clear color.

Comment: @VTT That was my first thought as well but my color is defined with full alpha, no opaqueness.

Comment: I think you need to switch to `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1` and set alpha mode to `DXGI_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED` because alpha is ignored by default.

Comment: @VTT I’ll give it a try, thank you for the suggestions. What confuses me is that the text is displayed normally when hooking from inside the process.

Comment: Normally fwfontwrapper already sets the state to pre-multiplied (since sprite sheets are built that way in the library) , can you post your drawtext/drawtextlayout code, one flag might be wrong?